# Gazebo and move_base problem

Tags: ros, gazebo, scan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte

I' simulating SLAM using gazebo and I followed Learning ROS book.

Now I reached move_base.launch but when I run it, it gave the following errors:

```
[ WARN] [1432083250.106400281,
919.561000000]: Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:  [ WARN] [1432083251.263770834,
923.948000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 923.948000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
```

Although, I proved that the laserscans are published by using:

```
rostopic echo scan
```

This is move_base file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
   <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find simulation)/maps/gazebo_map.yaml" output="screen">
</node>
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" >
  </include> 
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find simulation)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find simulation)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find simulation)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find simulation)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find simulation)/launch/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

and this is my tf tree:

[image: tf tree]

Any idea?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209531/gazebo-and-move_base-problem/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you are missing the `map` frame, as it does not appear on your tf tree. Try to add the following line to the launch file:

```
<!-- Place map frame at odometry frame -->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom_broadcaster"
      args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100"/>
```

That worked for me in the past.  It includes the transformation from `map` to `odom`. Which, in this case, is the same.

Probably, you can do a remap of the `odom` to `map` as well but, I am not sure that will work.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0